# Eigen Library - complex values in EigenSolver

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I want to rewrite to C++ eig function from Matlab:

```
[V,D] = eig(A,B) produces a diagonal matrix D of generalized
eigenvalues and a full matrix V whose columns are the corresponding
eigenvectors so that A*V = B*V*D.
```

I get positive results for Matrix4d class:

```
pair<Matrix4d, Vector4d> eig(const Matrix4d& A, const Matrix4d& B)
{
const Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix4d> solver(A, B);

const Matrix4d V = solver.eigenvectors();
const Vector4d D = solver.eigenvalues();

return pair<Matrix4d, Vector4d>(V, D);
}
```

The problem I face now is that eig in Matlab is capable of using complex numbers - what I need in my algorithm.

How can I change it to receive same/very similar effect with usage of Matrix4cd class instead of Matrix4d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't/can't use `auto` in davidhigh's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30208926/2899559) try this

```
std::pair<Matrix4cd, Vector4d> eig(const Matrix4cd& A, const Matrix4cd& B)
{
    Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix4cd> solver(A, B);

    Matrix4cd V = solver.eigenvectors();
    Vector4d D = solver.eigenvalues();

    return std::make_pair(V, D);
}
```

Comment: Ehh, half day lost and I didn't expect I would need to change cd do c on Vector4d. That compiled I have to test how it works tomorrow though, but for now you helped me to convert it. Both answers are right above and below. But as I work with vs2005 I will mark this one as right (would like to mark both...)

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `MatrixXd` by the complex version of it, `Matrix4cd` (which is actually a shortcut for `Matrix< std::complex < double >, Dynamic, 4 >`, see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html)):

```
std::pair<Matrix4cd, Vector4d> eig(const Matrix4cd& A, const Matrix4cd& B)
{
    Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix4cd> solver(A, B);

    Matrix4cd V = solver.eigenvectors();
    Vector4d D = solver.eigenvalues();

    return std::make_pair(V, D);
}
```

This is it already. Note however that you cannot pass arbitrary matrices, but the matrix `A` needs to be self-adjoint (also called hermitian) and `B` needs to be positive definite.

---

**EDIT**: thanks to the comment by @AviGinsburg, I corrected the mistake that the eigenvalues are *real* (and thus should be mapped to a real Eigen vector). Here is a C++14 implementation which gets around this problem (and so supports my stupidity ;-) ):

```
auto eig(const Matrix4cd& A, const Matrix4cd& B)
{
    Eigen::GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix4cd> solver(A, B);

    auto V = solver.eigenvectors();
    auto D = solver.eigenvalues();

    return std::make_pair(V, D);
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this at start. It returns error : YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY

Comment: @Avi Ginsburg: for me neither, because I haven't checked ... I was assuming the code in the OP compiles.

Comment: @F1sher: this is probably because you feed in a real matrix. In that case, you should pass `M.cast<std::complex<double> >()` instead.

Comment: @davidhigh The OPs code compiles. The problem is with the line `Vector4cd D = solver.eigenvalues();` which is trying to return a different type.

Comment: @AviGinsburg:  surely we have real eigenvalues .. how stupid :). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: How should I replace  Vector4cd D = solver.eigenvalues(); then if it causes compilation error (I've commented solver.eigenvalues(); and then in worked, but I still need eigenvalues)?

Comment: @davidhigh would you like to edit your answer or should I post a corrected one?

Comment: Hmm, this compiled:  Vector4cd D = solver.eigenvalues().cast<std::complex<double> >();

Comment: @F1sher Yes, but is incorrect. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't compile for me. Is that because I am using vs2005 and its C++14?